# xpath Expression for "or" operator

Tags: xpath

Can anyone please help me, I want to use or operator in my **xpath** expression to select all input or all a from an html page.
my expression is like this:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input or //a");
```

But I'm having errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the union operator:

```
//input | //a
```

Or an expression like this, which may perform somewhat better:

```
//*[self::input or self::a]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator is boolean OR in XPath, so `//input or //a` is a boolean expression which will return true if either of the node sets `//input` and `//a` are non-empty (i.e. within your source document there is at least one `input` element or one `a` element or both) and false otherwise.

Instead you're looking for the `|` operator which is the "union" operation on node sets.

```
//input | //a
```

will give you a set containing all the `input` elements *and* all the `a` elements.